# PHP Checking if first digit of a string is 1?

Tags: php, strlen

`PHP` Checking if first digit of a string is `1`.
How can I do this?
Also how can I check if a string is between `27-34`.
Would `strlen($variable) == 27-34` work?

Thanks.

Comment: `substr()`? `[]`? `intval()`? Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes but how can I set it to check only the first digit?

Comment: Find something useful here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: Not homework, lol.  Trying to check if a BTC address is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do both checks at once, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
$str = 'string to test';
if (preg_match('/^1.{26,33}$/', $str)) {
    // string starts with 1, and is 27-34 characters long
}
```

The regular expression I'm using is:

```
/       the start of the regular expression
^       the start of the string
1       a literal '1'
.       any character
{26,33} previous item repeated 26-33 times total
$       the end of the string
/       the end of the regular expression
```

Note that for if you're validating bitcoin addresses, they can start with a 3 as well. To allow that, you should replace the `1` in the regular expression with `[13]`:

```
'/^[13].{26,33}$/'
```

Also note that proper address validation should really be more thorough than this, and should verify the checksum as well to protect against copying or typing mistakes.

From [the bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address):

> If you would like to validate a Bitcoin address in an application, it is advisable to use a method from [this thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1026.0) rather than to just check for string length, allowed characters, or that the address starts with a 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've read the question incorrectly, you are wanting to know if the first digit in a string is the number 1 and that the string's length is between 27 and 34 characters.

Many of the answers are looking at the first character of the string, not the first digit in the string.

Anyway, here is a simple enough function with a tester. All tests pass (i.e. they correctly determine which ones have a digit in the string is 1). Empty strings, strings with no digits, short and long strings will all return false.

```
<?php

/**
 * Is the first digit in the string the number 1 and that the string's length is between 27 and 34.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return bool
 */ 
function checkString($string)
{
    return preg_match('`(\d)`', $string, $matches) && $matches[1] == '1' && strlen($string) >= 27 && strlen($string) <= 34;
}



class tester
{
    public function providePossibleStrings()
    {
        return [
            ['1', false],
            ['A1', false],
            ['21', false],
            ['A21', false],
            ['A', false],
            ['', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345678', true],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY01', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY012', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY0123', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY01234', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY012345', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY0123456', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY01234567', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY012345678', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ02', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ023', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0234', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ02345', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ023456', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0234567', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ02345678', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ023456789', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567891', false],
            ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567890', false],
        ];
    }

    public function testCheckString($value, $result)
    {
        echo($result == checkString($value) ? 'Pass' : 'Fail'), ' : ', $value, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$tester = new tester();
foreach ($tester->providePossibleStrings() as $testParams) {
    call_user_func_array([$tester, 'testCheckString'], $testParams);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Q1) Checking if first digit of a string is 1?

A1) `preg_match("/^1/", $yourNumber)`. return 1 for true, 0 for false
A1b) to ensure the value is number, `preg_match("/^1\d*$/", $yourNumber)`

Q2) check if a string is between 27-34.

A2) `if($yourNumber >= 27 && $yourNumber <= 34)`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'preg_match' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\address_process.php on line 24

Comment: Can I know yourNumber value and which answer you used (A1 ? A1b?)

Answer (score -1):

To check if the first digit of a string is 1 you can do this:

```
$string = "1fjiofwjoie";
if($string[0] == 1)
{
    // First digit is 1
}

else
{
    // First digit is not 1
}
```

As for checking a string is between 27 and 34 you could do this:

```
if($string >= 27 && $string <= 34)
{
    // Code here
}
```

If you mean the string length, do this:

```
if(strlen($string) >= 27 && strlen($string) <= 34)
{
    // Code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(substr("your_string_here",0, 1)=="1")
echo "Yes, the first character is 1";

if(("the_string">27)&("the_string"<34))
echo "Yes, the string lies between 27 and 34";
```